# check if number string contains decimal?

Tags: javascript, regex, math, decimal, sqrt

After doing a sqrt()

How can I be check to see if the result contains only whole numbers or not?

I was thinking Regex to check for a decimal - if it contains a decimal, that means it didn't root evenly into whole numbers. Which would be enough info for me.

but this code isnt working...

```
result = sqrt(stringContainingANumber);
decimal = new RegExp(".");
document.write(decimal.test(result));
```

I bet there's other ways to accomplish the same thing though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if a number has a decimal place/is a whole number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304052/check-if-a-number-has-a-decimal-place-is-a-whole-number)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

. means any char.
You have to quote the dot. "\."

Or you could test

```
if (result > Math.floor(result)) {
   // not an decimal
}
```

Comment: That made the most sense to me. Thanks mate!

Comment: Sure, since javascript number is a double having about 15 digits precision. So you have to watch for numerical errors of certain result ranges

Comment: What about "42.00".

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `%` operator:

```
result % 1 === 0;  // rest after dividing by 1 should be 0 for whole numbers
```

Comment: But, I'm assuming that `result` is the already a number here as it's the result of the `sqrt()` function.  I'm not sure you're solving what the OP asked.

Comment: @jfriend00: Good catch. Then it's even more straight-forward to use the `%` operator I guess.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf):

```
​var myStr = "1.0";
myStr.indexOf("."); // Returns 1

// Other examples
myStr.indexOf("1"); // Returns 0 (meaning that "1" may be found at index 0)
myStr.indexOf("2"); // Returns -1 (meaning can't be found)
```

Comment: +1 for using `.indexOf()` instead of a regex since it's simpler and faster than a regex for this particular problem.

Answer (score 1):

"." has meaning in the regex syntax which is "anything"  you need to escape it using "\."

Answer (score 0):

If its a string we can just use split function and then check the length of the array returned. If its more than 1 it has decimal point else not :). This doesn't work for numbers though :(. Please see the last edit. It works for string as well now :)

```
function checkDecimal() {
    var str = "202.0";
    var res = str.split(".");
    alert(res.length >1);
    var str1 = "20";

    alert(str1.split(".").length>1);
 }
```

Hope it helps someone.
Happy Learning :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for checking string containing decimal digits ,
you can try like this

```
var num = "123.677";
if (!isNaN(Number(num)) {
alert("decimal no");
}
else {
alert("Not a decimal number");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry. This answer is too late. but I hope this will help.

```
function isThisDecimal(val){
  if (!(val.indexOf(".") == -1)){
    return true; // decimal 
  }
  return false; // number
}

console.log(isThisDecimal("12.00")); //true
console.log(isThisDecimal("12.12")); //true
console.log(isThisDecimal("12"));// false
```