# Rounding decimal numbers using toFixed

Tags: javascript, rounding

I have small issue with the JavaScript function `toFixed(2)`.

If I round this decimal number `45.24859`, I get `45.25` using this function.

But my problem is, if I round `10` (it has no decimal part), the function will return a decimal number `10.00`.

How can I fix this issue?

My problem is, if enter a number without a decimal part, the function should return a non decimal number.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Round up to 2 decimal places in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832914/round-up-to-2-decimal-places-in-javascript)

Comment: please note that this has NOTHING to do with jQuery in the slightest.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another way to solve this

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/254L4/1/)

[.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

```
function roundNumber(num){
   return (num.toString().indexOf(".") !== -1) ? num.toFixed(2) : num;
}
```

---

Below solution not compatible with all browsers.

<strike>or</strike>

```
function roundNumber(num){
   return (num.toString().contains(".")) ? num.toFixed(2) : num;
}
```

[.contains()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/contains)

Comment: @rplg Fixed the issue check now.

Answer (score 6):

We can check the number is decimal or not with this [Check if a number has a decimal...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304052/check-if-a-number-has-a-decimal-place-is-a-whole-number)

So combining that you can use this function

```
function roundNumber(num){
   return num % 1 != 0 ? num.toFixed(2) : num;
}
```

Or I think better option will be to use

```
Math.round(num * 100) / 100
```

Comment: You didn't handle the case of 10.1 to 10.10

Comment: 10.1 should be 10.10 rt ..?