# How to identify input if its decimal in javascript

Tags: javascript

I've created a code on where i can try out javascript's conditions and the code goes like this: the user enter's a decimal number and an alert box will say that it is a decimal number.If it is not a decimal number, an alert box will pop up and say that it is not a decimal number. However, the problem is I don't know what to put in my IF conditional statement to identify if its decimal.

Here is my code:

```
 var a = document.getElementById("txt1").value;

 if (a == ?){
    alert("It is a decimal number!");
 } else {
    alert("It is not a decimal number!");
 }
```

I hope someone can help me out. A total beginner. Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304052/check-if-a-number-has-a-decimal-place-is-a-whole-number

Comment: `if (/^-?\d+(\.\d+)?$/.test(input))` this is might be good enough for you. also google never hurts.

Comment: I think a further definition of what you mean by `decimal` would help. Some examples of what would and would not be acceptable inputs from a user. Edit your question and you even earn a badge.

Answer (score 1):

The elegant way is to use regular expression but sometimes regular expressions can
frustrate novice programmers. Check this example. I hope it helps you.

```
var a = document.getElementById("txt1").value;

if (!isNaN(parseFloat(a)) && a.toString().indexOf(".") == -1){
    alert("It is a decimal number!");
} else {
    alert("It is not a decimal number!");
}
```

Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example-

```
var a = prompt("Type in any number");

var b = parseInt(a);

if(a !== b) {
    alert("This is a decimal number!");
}
else {
    alert("This is an integer");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use RegEx.

```js
var value = prompt('Enter decimal here senpai', '0.0');

if (/^\d*\.?\d*$/.test(value)) {
    console.log('I\'m a decimal. Nya~');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
     function decimal_only(e) {

         var charCode = (e.which) ? e.which : window.event.keyCode
         if (charCode != 46 && charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
             return false;
         }

         if (charCode == 46) { //Now Check The Decimal only allow 1 decimal
             if (e.value.indexOf('.') > -1) {
                 return false;
             }
         }
         return true;
     }
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use a simple check

```
if(a != Math.floor(a))
{
  alert("It is a decimal number!");
} else {
        alert("It is not a decimal number!");
}
```

or

```
if(a - Math.floor(a) != 0) //then its with decimal
{
    alert("It is a decimal number!");
} else {
    alert("It is not a decimal number!");
}
```

Comment: Since when is `"Hello World"` a decimal number?

Comment: Consider a situation a user passes some number in the input

Comment: The question is how to intercept a user not typing a decimal number. `"Foo"` is not a decimal number, but your code won't intercept that. Hence it's wrong.