# Javascript validation to only allow positive and negative Integers...no decimals

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey I just need a standard JS validation to allow a string with just positive or negative #'s and no decimals.

```
1 = true
10 = true
-10 = true
-1.5 = false
1.5 = false
```

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14636536/how-to-check-if-a-variable-is-an-integer-in-javascript

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304052/check-if-a-number-has-a-decimal-place-is-a-whole-number

Answer (score 0):

This one uses Regular Expression:

```
function isInteger(n) {
    return (typeof n == 'number' && /^[-]?[0-9]+$/.test(n+''));
}
```

This one works with strings too:

```
function isInteger(n) {
    return /^[-]?[0-9]+$/.test(n+'');
}
```

It's based on macloving's answer at [How to check if a variable is an integer in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14636536/how-to-check-if-a-variable-is-an-integer-in-javascript)

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jyrkim/2u9xndd4/1/)