# fancybox doesn't handle widths with decimal values

Tags: jquery, css, fancybox, fancybox-2

It was noticed that when fancybox is calculating how wide it needs to be to fit the content, it doesn't handle decimal places/floating point numbers.

For example if we had 2 `<div>` of `300px` and `217.367px` respectively, fancybox would round the `width` of its content to `300px + 217px = 517px`. This means the second `div` would not fit and would therefore drop down to the next line.

It seems this is due to the use of the jQuery `width()` method.

**Relevant code**

*html* :

```
<a class="fancybox" href="#inline">open inline</a>

<div id="inline" class="cf">
    <div id="content">
         <h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
        <p>More text content etc</p>
    </div>
    <div id="red">Other floating content</div>
</div>
```

*css* :

```
#inline {
    position: relative;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
#content {
    width: 15.526em; /* 217.367px */
    height: 150px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
#red {
    height: 150px;
    width: 300px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
```

*jQuery* :

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    padding: 0
});
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/fbqo9e35/)**

**Notice** in the fiddle the `#inline` container is always visible for demonstration purposes only. Also notice the `width` of one of the containers was set in `ems`, which is a pretty common scenario so changing it to a fixed `width` in `px` may not be the way to go (although it's possible to set `width: 217.367px` on the *css* with the same result)

Is there a fix or a workaround?

A possible and easy solution would be to add an extra pixel to the fancybox container but it would be better to add it only when it's needed and not as a general rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since using the jQuery `.width()` method will always return a rounded value of the element's `width`, even within the `parseFloat()` *function* :

```
parseFloat($("#element").width());
```

see **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pnzq0u1k/1/)**

... we would need to get the **computed** `width` of each element within the fancybox content to get an incremental total `width` of the fancybox container.

To do this, we can use [`getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.getComputedStyle) along with the `getPropertyValue("width")` method to get the **computed** `width` of each element like :

```
var compWidth = window.getComputedStyle(element).getPropertyValue("width");
```

**Notice** that `compWidth` will return the string `248.417px` so we still need to parse the *floating* value to get the right calculation. We could do something like :

```
parseFloat(compWidth.split("px")[0]);
```

Then, we can compare if the total **computed** `width` has a *remainder* to decide whether we should add an extra pixel to the fancybox container or not. We can achieve this by using a *modulo* operation (Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2304062/1055987) for reference) like :

```
if (totalWidth % 1 != 0) {
    totalWidth++; // or Math.ceil(totalWidth);
}
```

See the full code with calculations within the `afterLoad` callback :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        padding: 0,
        afterLoad: function () {
            // get the computed width of elements inside fancybox
            var totalWidth = 0;
            $("#inline").find("div").each(function (i) {
                // increment total width with each element's width
                totalWidth += parseFloat(
                window.getComputedStyle(this)
                      .getPropertyValue("width")
                      .split("px")[0]);
            });
            // compare if the result has a remainder
            if (totalWidth % 1 != 0) {
                // increase total width by 1px
                totalWidth++; // or Math.ceil(totalWidth);
                // set the new fancybox width
                $.extend(this, {
                    fitToView: false, // cause will set a fixed width
                    autoWidth: false,
                    width: totalWidth
                });
            }
        }
    });
}); // ready
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rtvftx2t/)**

**NOTE**: this is a workaround that can be useful for some specific scenarios. Also notice `getComputedStyle()` is only supported in IE9+