# Check whether obj.value has decimal part or not

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm working in an existing project in `angularjs` and I'm newbie.

I have the following code:

```
<td ng-if="obj.value != ''">{{obj.value}}</td>
```

I need to check whether `obj.value` has decimal part or not. I yes I want to limit the decimal part to 1 digit.

I tried `<td ng-if="obj.value != ''">{{obj.value|number:1}}</td>` but converts also integer values to decimals.

Any ideas?

Comment: So if it is 10, you just want 10 and not 10.0 ?

Comment: I don't know Angular syntax, but have you tried something like `<td ng-if= "obj.value != '' " && ng-if= " obj.value % 1 == 0 " >{{obj.value|number:1}}</td>`? - [Reference to check if a number is float in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304052/check-if-a-number-has-a-decimal-place-is-a-whole-number)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do it like this:

```
<td ng-if="obj.value != ''">{{obj.value | number: obj.value % 1 === 0 ? 0 : 1}}</td>
```

You find a more detailed explanation about the number pipe here in [this documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/number)  and regarding checking integer there are multiple answers but you can refer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885817/how-do-i-check-that-a-number-is-float-or-integer) for them.