# Only accept whole numbers, no decimals

Tags: javascript

I need my code to only accept whole numbers, no decimals and should prompt an error when a decimal gets entered. I don't want a new function , I'm hoping I can just add lines to my function but I don't know what I need to add.

```js
function number_function() {

  number = parseInt(prompt('Enter a positive integer:'));


  if (number < 0) {
    alert('Error! Factorial for negative number does not exist. But I will show you the positive number');
    number = number * -1;
    let n = 1;
    for (i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
      n *= i;
    }
    alert("The factorial of " + number + " is " + n + ".");


  } else if (number === 0) {
    alert("Please enter a number greater than 0");
  } else {
    let n = 1;
    for (i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
      n *= i;
    }
    alert("The factorial of " + number + " is " + n + ".");
  }
}

number_function();
```

Comment: "I don't want a new function" why though? Functions are good we shd use them ...

Comment: Should the user be able to use thousands separators?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if a number has a decimal place/is a whole number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304052/check-if-a-number-has-a-decimal-place-is-a-whole-number)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this to check if the number has decimals

```js
const val = 10.7 % 1;

if (val !== 0) {
  console.log('has decimals');
} else {
  console.log('has no decimal');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript provides the built-in function `Number.isInteger(n)`