# Is there a shorter way to remove whole numbers with if statements?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

This is a simplified version of the code which removes whole numbers with if statements:

```js
function F1() {
  A = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100 + 1));
  B = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100 + 1));
  Dez = document.getElementById("Dez").innerHTML = A / B;
  if (Math.round(Dez * 10) !== Dez * 10) {
    F1();
  }
  if (Dez <= 0) {
    F1();
  }
  
  if (Dez === 1) {
    F1();
  }

  if (Dez === 2) {
    F1();
  }

//...

  if (Dez === 100) {
    F1();
  }


}
```

```html
<button onclick="F1()"> New </button>
<label id="Dez"></label>
```

Is there a shorter way to remove whole numbers with if statements?
I want a shorter solution for this part of the code:

```js
if (Dez === 1) {
  F1();
}

if (Dez === 2) {
  F1();
}

if (Dez === 3) {
  F1();
}

...

if (Dez === 100) {
  F1();
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if a number has a decimal place/is a whole number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304052/check-if-a-number-has-a-decimal-place-is-a-whole-number)

Comment: Not simply a better way, but your code doesn't work.

Comment: I find this question very fascinating, but probably not for the reason you think.  The possible outcomes of choosing A,B from [1,100] and choosing the quotient that has exactly one non-zero digit after the decimal place are quite interesting and have a fascinating probability distribution.  Are you actually attached to that probability distribution?  (e.g.: `1.5` is 33x more likely to be generated than `49.5`) Because if you're not, then there's a completely different way to select one of the 170 possible outcomes with uniform distribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if the value is a whole number with `% 1 === 0`:

```js
function F1() {
  let A, B, Dez;
  do {
    A = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100 + 1));
    B = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100 + 1));
    Dez = A / B;
  } while (Math.round(Dez * 10) !== Dez * 10 || Dez % 1 === 0);
  document.getElementById("Dez").textContent = Dez;
}
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', F1);
```

```html
<button> New </button>
<label id="Dez"></label>
```

Also remember to:

- Declare your variables, like I did - don't implicitly create global variables
- Only use `.innerHTML` when inserting HTML markup - otherwise, better to use `.textContent`, it's faster, safer, and more semantically appropriate
- Consider avoiding inline handlers, they have some [terrible scoping rules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59539045) and can be difficult to manage, better to use `addEventListener` instead