# How to display the rows in a float column that contains decimals?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame that has a quantity column and I need to check if the data was inputted correctly. If there's a number that was inputted with decimals I receive de data frame with de quantity column as a float and not as an integer, but I need to print out the index of the rows that were inputted with decimals.

For example

```
data = {'quantity':  [2.00, 1.00, 3.00, 4.55, 5.00, 6.22]
        }

testdf = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I need to print out the index of the rows that contain the decimal values that are not .00

Answer (score 0):

You can compare the values to the rounded versions of the values and use boolean masking to select only those rows

```
testdf[testdf['quantity']!=testdf['quantity'].round()]\
.index\
.tolist()

[3, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to use the modulo operator, as [in this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304052/check-if-a-number-has-a-decimal-place-is-a-whole-number#:%7E:text=You%20can%20multiply%20it%20by,number%20is%20a%20whole%20number.), and then extract the indexes that satisfy the condition to a list:

```py
print(testdf[(testdf.quantity % 1) != 0].index.tolist())

[3, 5]
```